# clojure sendoff println function

Tags: clojure, stm

I am trying to `send-off` function `println` in the transaction.

```
(ns com.lapots.functional.clojure.transact
    (:gen-class))

(defn transfer [from to amount]
    (alter
        (.balance from) - amount)
     (alter
        (.balance from) + amount))

(defrecord Account [balance])

(defn -main [& args]
    (def account1 (Account. (ref 100)))
    (def account2 (Account. (ref 100)))
    (def trx-agent (agent 0))

    (future
        (dosync
            (send-off trx-agent println "T2 transfer")
            (Thread/sleep 5000)
            (transfer account1 account2 10)))

    (dosync
        (println "T1 transfer")
        (transfer account1 account2 10))

    (shutdown-agents)
)
```

If I do like this

```
(println "T2 transfer")
(Thread/sleep 5000)
```

it displays message twice as the transaction retries. So I decided to use `agents` to make side-effecting operation `println` run only once.

But when I do like this

```
(send-off trx-agent println "T2 transfer")
```

It does not print `T2 transfer` message at all. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `shutdown-agents` too soon.

```
(defn transfer [from to amount]
  (println :transfer-enter amount)
  (alter
    (.balance from) - amount)
  (alter
    (.balance from) + amount)
  (println :transfer-exit  amount)
)

(defrecord Account [balance])

(def account1 (Account. (ref 100)))
(def account2 (Account. (ref 100)))
(def trx-agent (agent 0))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println :main-enter )

  (future
    (dosync
      (println :t2-enter)
      (send-off trx-agent println "agent: T2 transfer")
      (Thread/sleep 500)
      (transfer account1 account2 20)
      (println :t2-exit)
    ))

  (dosync
    (println :t1-enter)
    (send-off trx-agent println "agent: T1 transfer")
    (transfer account1 account2 10)
    (println :t1-exit))

  (Thread/sleep 2000)
  (shutdown-agents)
  (println :main-exit )
)
```

with result:

```
:main-enter
:t2-enter
:t1-enter
:transfer-enter 10
:transfer-exit 10
:t1-exit
0 agent: T1 transfer
:transfer-enter 20
:t2-enter
:transfer-enter 20
:transfer-exit 20
:t2-exit
nil agent: T2 transfer
:main-exit
```

So T2 only waits 500 msec now, while T1 runs right away. We wait 2000 msec before calling `shutdown-agents`, which will kill all of the agent threads preventing the agent from running.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Basically before invoking `println transfer` I wait 10 seconds (transaction retried) but by the time it is commited the agents are shutdown

Answer (score 1):

I see at least three things wrong with your code fragment:

1. Your `transfer` function

   ```
   (defn transfer [from to amount]
     (alter
       (.balance from) - amount)   ;; <======== from - amount
     (alter
       (.balance from) + amount))  ;; <======== from + amount
   ```

   It looks like you actually want to say alter `from` and then alter `to`
2. From the `send-off` docs:

   > Dispatch a potentially blocking action to an agent. Returns the agent
   >   immediately. Subsequently, in a separate thread, the state of the
   >   agent will be set to the value of:  (apply action-fn state-of-agent
   >   args)

   So I think you don't need that future. Also the line

   ```
   (send-off trx-agent println "T2 transfer")
   ```

   means that you are setting the state of the agent to the result of

   ```
   (println state-of-agent "T2 transfer")`
   ```

   which is `nil`, since `println` always returns `nil`. I don't think 
   that's what you want.
3. You have a race condition in you `transfer` function. Since you are not modifying the `from` and `to` atomically there is a possibility of a race there.

Comment: But as I invoke `transfer` inside transaction it should be atomic in any case, no?

Comment: Well I just want to display the message. Is there a way to avoid displaying the state?

Comment: > But as I invoke transfer inside transaction it should be atomic in any case, no?

Yes that is correct. But then the correctness of `transfer` depends on "how" it is invoked, which is not a nice property.

To be honest I don't really understand the whole purpose of your code. What exactly are you trying to print?

Comment: Well generally speaking, the only reason I used function `transfer` there is that to show it later out of other code haha. Generally aside testing or demonstration purposes there are not any other purposes.